# Differential equation: which substitution leads to this solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The second order differential equation:

$$xy''+2y'+\lambda^2 xy=0,$$

where $y=f(x), \lambda \in\mathrm{R}$, has the following solution:

$$y(x)=c_1\frac{\cos \lambda x}{x}+c_2\frac{\sin \lambda x}{x},$$

which I obtained using WolframAlpha's DSolve. But I don't have access to the paid version, so cannot see the step-by-step integration.

I suspect the result can be obtained by means of a fairly simple substitution. If so, **which one?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the change $u=xy.$ That is $y=\dfrac{u}{x}.$ Note that

$$y'=\dfrac{u'}{x}-\dfrac{u}{x^2}$$ and

$$y''=\dfrac{u''}{x}-\dfrac{2u'}{x^2}+\dfrac{2u}{x^3}.$$ Thus the equation becomes

$$u''+\lambda^2u=0.$$

Comment: Oh dear. I tried that one earlier and didn't get it to work. Must have made a small algebraical error somewhere. Thanks very much.